# filesystem 'tank/volume' cannot be mounted, unable to open the dataset

Tags: zfs

I'm running ZFS and after zfs clone of a snapshot, I tried to mount the volume with command

mount -t zfs tank/volume /mnt

, but got an error message:

filesystem 'tank/volume' cannot be mounted, unable to open the dataset

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the volume running ext4 and not zfs. Try just plain mount without the filesystem type defined, and use /dev/zvol/ as path, then mount uses filesystem type autodetection:

```
mount /dev/zvol/tank/volume /mnt
```